# Delete an object in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to understand the delete operation of an object in aws S3. 
In cross region replication, if I delete an object from the source, this delete is not propagated to the destination.

> The official text - "If you specify an object version ID to delete in
>   a DELETE request, Amazon S3 deletes that object version in the source
>   bucket, but it doesn't replicate the deletion in the destination
>   bucket. In other words, it doesn't delete the same object version from
>   the destination bucket. This protects data from malicious deletions. "

In other case, I read that

> The official text - Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for
>   overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all Regions

When I made a test, the delete is not propagated. Then, there is a divergence between the replica !

Is it normal ? how about the eventual consistency of the delete ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not about replication, it's about simple buckets from Introduction to AWS S3.

> Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all Regions

The right answer - "it doesn't delete the same object version from the destination bucket. This protects data from malicious deletions".

If you need "consistency of the delete" - you can try to automate it with `aws s3 sync` with `--delete` flag.